logic gates codingame struggles
Im new to C and i really need your help
Detail: https://www.codingame.com/training/easy/logic-gates
All of that works okey (for me), except printf("%c ",output_name[0][i]);
My idea is print the name first then "-" and "_" but my code only work with one-character name, i tried several ways but still not work.
Here is my code
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int m;
    scanf("%d", &m);
    char input_name[n][9];
    char input_signal[n][26];

    char output_name[m][1];
    char type[m][5];
    char input_name_1[m][1];
    char input_name_2[m][1]; 
    int input_value_store_1;
    int input_value_store_2;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%s%s", input_name[i], input_signal[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {  
        scanf("%s%s%s%s", output_name[i], type[i], input_name_1[i], input_name_2[i]);
    }
    
    for (int i=0; i < m; i++) {
        printf("%c ",output_name[0][i]); 
        for (int j=0; j<sizeof(input_signal[i]); j++)
            {
                if (input_signal[0][j] == '-' ) input_value_store_1 = 1; 
                else input_value_store_1 = 0;

                if (input_signal[1][j] == '-' ) input_value_store_2 = 1; 
                else input_value_store_2 = 0;
                

                if (strcmp(type[i], "AND") == 0) {
                    if ((input_value_store_1 == 1) && (input_value_store_2 == 1))
                        printf("-");
                    else printf("_"); 
                } 

                else if (strcmp(type[i], "OR") == 0) {
                    if ((input_value_store_1 == 1) || (input_value_store_2 == 1))
                        printf("-");
                    else printf("_"); 
                }

                else if (strcmp(type[i], "XOR") == 0) {
                    if (((input_value_store_1 == 1) || (input_value_store_2 == 1)) && (input_value_store_1 != input_value_store_2))
                        printf("-");
                    else printf("_"); 
                }

                else if (strcmp(type[i], "NAND") == 0) {
                    if (!((input_value_store_1 == 1) && (input_value_store_2 == 1)))
                        printf("-");
                    else printf("_"); 
                }

                else if (strcmp(type[i], "NOR") == 0) {
                    if (!((input_value_store_1 == 1) || (input_value_store_2 == 1)))
                        printf("-");
                    else printf("_"); 
                }

                else if (strcmp(type[i], "NXOR") == 0) {
                    if (!(((input_value_store_1 == 1) || (input_value_store_2 == 1)) && (input_value_store_1 != input_value_store_2)))
                        printf("-");
                    else printf("_"); 
                }
            }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}


With the definition char output_name[m][1]; each element on output_name will only have space for one single character. All it can hold is an empty string, that contains only the string null terminator. Nothing else. You're trying to read (and print) more characters than can fit in output_name[i]. That leads to undefined behavior.

Note that you're also not checking the return values from scanf. If they failed for whatever reason, m and n could be uninitialized when creating your variable length arrays, which puts us in UB territory.

You also appear to be using parallel arrays to hold multiple pieces of data about multiple distinct "things". You probably want to define a struct and have an array of those structures to hold those related pieces of data.
